# Python NamedTuple to C++ Struct

Tags: c++, python-2.7, struct, namedtuple

I have searched the internet for hours at this point. Does anyone know how to parse a namedtuple returned from a python function into a struct or just into separate variables. The part I am having trouble with is getting the data out of the returned pointer. I am calling a python function embedded in C++ using the PyObject_CallFunction() call and I don't know what to do once I have the PyObject* to the returned data.

I am using Python 2.7 for reference.

EDIT: I ended up moving all of the functionality I was trying to do in both Python and C++ to just Python for now. I will update in the near future about attempting the strategy suggested in the comments of this question.

Comment: You may have trouble converting namedtuple since it's not a builtin. Try converting namedtuple to tuple first (from python level), then use `PyArg_ParseTuple` in your C++ extension.

Comment: @thorhunter I'll give that a shot. I was a little confused when reading the documentation for PyArg_ParseTuple as to how to access each part. Do I have to know exactly how many bytes Python used to store the values?

Comment: No, the only thing you need to know is the structure of tuple you're passing, eg. (int, int, string). Then you can bind these to C types using `PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "iis", &int1, &int2, &str);` for `int int1; int int2; char* str` variables. This is, of course, a basic example, you can do much more using `PyArg_ParseTuple` and other Python API elements. You'll be able to extract any information from PyObject you need (including  string length) using Python API one way or another. I found this reference quite simple to follow: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ext/parseTuple.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am calling a python function embedded in C++ using the
>   PyObject_CallFunction() call and I don't know what to do once I have
>   the PyObject* to the returned data.

A `namedtuple` is a tuple subclass that additionally exposes tuple elements as named attributes. This means that you can choose whether to access its data as `obj[position]` or `obj.attribute`. The latter is generally more readable, but the former combines well with tuple unpacking. In Python/C, it is probably easier to access it as tuple, since then you can use the convenience function `PyArg_ParseTuple`, as indicated in the comment.

To extract arbitrary attributes of an object (not necessarily a `namedtuple`), one would call `PyObject_GetAttrString`. Given an object describing, say, a point, extracting an attribute such as `x` might look like this:

```
PyObject *point = ...;  // assume we get a new reference to point
if (!point)
  return NULL;
PyObject *x = PyObject_GetAttrString(point, "x");
if (!x) {
  // obj.x raised, possibly because point is of a different type
  Py_DECREF(point);
  return NULL;
}
double x_val = PyFloat_AsDouble(x);
Py_DECREF(x);     // x not used below this line
if (x_val == -1 && PyErr_Occurred()) {
  // obj.x is not float or float-like
  Py_DECREF(point);
  return NULL;
}
Py_DECREF(point); // point not used below this line
```

The error checking and reference counting is quite tedious, but it can be mostly eliminated using guard classes or, better yet, using the classes written by others, such as Boost.Python.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative method. Why do you do the same check twice on 'x_val && PyErr_Ocurred()' with what looks like the same contents in the if statement?

Comment: @Wired365 Just a copy-paste error, sorry. The code I originally wrote also intended to fetch `y`, but with error checking and referencex counting, it turned out too long. I've edited the answer to remove the extra copy, and also changed `throw ...` to `return NULL`, since that's what you typically want to do in Python/C. (If you plan to ignore the error and continue, remember to call `PyErr_Clear`, and possibly `PyErr_ExceptionMatches` to make sure that you're only ignoring the exceptions you want to ignore, not every exception out there.)

Comment: ahhh okay that's what I thought it might be, but I just wanted to make sure I understood you completely. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: In my 2.7.6 installation, the attributes are exposed as properties rather than just attributes.  So they have `fget`/`fset` available, too.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich Can you elaborate on that - why would one care *how* the attributes are implemented? Is there some advantage to using `fget` and `fset` instead of the regular attribute access/mutation API?

Comment: @user4815162342, one example, which I tend to use, is to improve readability when using accessors as the functions passed to `map` and `filter`.  It can be done with lambda's too, but something like `map(T.a.fget, some_iterable_of_Ts` looks cleaner than `map(lambda t:t.a, some_iterable_of_Ts)`.  There may also be a slight speed up because lambda's don't need to be compiled for each such call (because `fget` gets baked in when namedtuple builds a class).

Comment: @user4815162342, btw, (and this is off topic but you might find it useful) if you like guards and Boost.Python, you might also like the BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT macro.  It lets you setup RAII in-place in the code.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich Bypassing the descriptor protocol and talking to the implementation of a property should **never** be done without good reason. The whole point of having descriptors is that code shouldn't *care* whether an attribute is implemented with `property` or with e.g. a Cython callable. What you describe breaks duck typing and inheritance (where the iterable could easily produce an object that has `a`, but doesn't use `T.a.fget` as the actual getter), at least.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich Also note that a lambda is not "compiled for each call", it is compiled exactly once, along with the rest of the module. If you want to avoid a lambda for performance or other reasons, use `operator.attrgetter`.

Comment: @user4815162342, I was talking about using named tuples within a script. As far as I know, `fget`/`fset` is part of the Property protocol rather than just a particul implementation of Property.  So using it for convenience is fair game.  As far as lambda's comment, it would only be true for lambda's defined at module scope.  Lambda's are bound to their *calling* context.  To be more clear, you can expect the `id()` of the lambda to be different every time.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich The whole point of duck typing is that you can get other types that *pretend* to be the original types (`namedtuple` instances in this case). While `fget` is a public member of `property`, it is specific to `property` and does not extend to other descriptor implementations. There is no guarantee that `namedtuple` accessors will always be implemented as `property`, an optimized future implementation (or the one in PyPy) might use other means to implement attributes. On the other hand, you have shown no **upside** to bypassing the descriptor protocol here.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich You are describing closures and yes, a new lambda object is created each time, **but** that doesn't mean that the code is **compiled** from scratch in each go. Check the `__code__` attribute of such lambdas and you will find that they share the same code object, which is of course compiled only once, when the code is loaded.

Comment: @user4815162342, I didn't say lambdas had to be compiled *from scratch* every time.  And they may very well be *partially* compiled in some implementations.  I did mention that a slight performance improvement in this case would be just a side-effect.  The main reason for taking advantage of Property accessors is readability.  And since the collections module implements namedtuple purely in Python, I don't think it's necessary to worry about different implementations of Python itself.  Using `attrgetter` instead of `fget` is mostly a choice when both are available. The upside is readability.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich I will not quibble with you regarding the lambdas, just look up your own comments. In conclusion, using `type(x).attr.fget` instead of `x.attr` is not only less readable, it breaks duck typing and unnecessarily constrains attribute implementation, for no gain whatsoever. The idea deserves no more of my time.

Comment: @user4815162342, I don't know why you quibble at all.  All I mentioned was that nametuple has the extra benefit of having pre-baked unbound accessors which can be taken advantage of.  You seem to insist that this is an implementation detail rather than a feature.  I think it's an undocumented feature.  Your last comment demonstrates a situation in which using an unbound accessor is less convenient than the bound one.  I've mentioned twice that this was not the use case I had in mind.  Using fget won't break duck typing.  If it goes away, the code will fail early.

Answer (score 1):

`namedtuple` is implemented purely in Python.  You can see its full source in collections.py.  It's very short.  The thing to keep in mind is that `namedtuple` itself is a function which creates a class in the frame in which it is called and then returns this class (not an instance of this class).  And it is this returned class that is then used to create instances.  So the object which you get is not what you want to pass into C++ if you want to pass individual instances.

C++ creates `struct` definitions at compile time.  `namedtuple` creates namedtuple classes at run time.  If you want to bind them to C++ structs, either use the PyObject to create your newly minted class' instances inside of C++ and assign them to `struct` elements at compile time.  Or create the newly minted class' instances in Python and pass them to C++.

Or you can use `_asdict` method (provided by namedtuple factory method for all classes it builds) and pass that to C++ to then do the binding of run-time defined data to compile-time defined data.

If you really want to do the bulk of the work in C++, you may also use the Struct module instead of using namedtuple.

namedtuple is really the swiss-army knife of Python for data which stays in Python.  It gives positional access, named access, and all the elements are also "properties" (so they have `fget` accessor method which can be used in maps, filters, etc. instead of having to write your own lambdas).

It's there for things like DB binding (when you don't know which columns will be there at run time). It's less clunky than OrderedDict for converting data from one format into another.  When it's used that way, the overhead of processing strings is nothing compared to actual access of the db (even embedded).  But I wouldn't use namedtuple for large arrays of structs which are meant to be used in calculations.